# Global Detect file info before opened with C++ or C#

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi, monitoring

**How can I get files info before Opened With Default App Like As Antivirus Check?**

---

Now I Wanna get Files Path before Opened default on windows .

- I start with Hooks I see i only can get From them Double Clicked or clicked and this library doesn't get any Parameter of Which File is Double Clicked!
- After that i think how can i change default open function of windows and write my function on this with working on Winapi - and i don't find any thing.
- Again i search that and find FileWatcher C# library and this is good but it's not response on fileOpen
- Again i search that and find FileDrive C++ But I didn't Find Any Good Source that worked and also good tutorial
- Again i search for I/O Monitoring and Log Files are Opening SO found two link [Eldos-CallBackFilter](https://www.eldos.com/cbflt) [this is need reg-key and without this not work for thest] and Also [MSDN-CDFS File System Drive](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/cdfs-File-System-Driver-0566e53a) [that this is need WDK 8.1 Update ] until i don't download that it's take some day long for me for download that.

So Do you have any Idea , Advice , resource and Some Place , Tutorial for this ?

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
thanks

Comment: You need to create a *Filter Driver* which is presumably what the commercial library you posted does. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531800/how-does-a-windows-antivirus-hook-into-the-file-access-process This is a non-trivial exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could look into the [File System Minifilter Drivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff540402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which are a little less fragile/error prone then writing a full blown Filter Driver.

Found a [sample project](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/Scanner-File-System-426c8cbe/view/Discussions#content) on MSDN Code Gallery, seems like a nice start, I didn't really dive into it, but again it seems like a good start.