# preventing malware transfer to computer from USB

Tags: usb, data-transfer, malware

Is there any code solution preventing data transfer from an attached USB drive to computer?
That is while data transfer from computer to USB is allowed is being run.
Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're looking for a Windows-based solution, you can write a [file system filter driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn641617) to prevent reading files from USB drives, much like how anti-virus software intercepts file access. However, with bootable USB devices and [BadUSB](https://srlabs.de/badusb/), there's more than one way for malware to attack a system.

For more information on intercepting file system access, see [How does a Windows antivirus hook into the file access process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531800/how-does-a-windows-antivirus-hook-into-the-file-access-process)